# Travelling alone to Brasil

Tags: recommendations

I'm Chilean and I want to go to Brazil next summer (that is, either January or March, I want to avoid February because of the carnival). So I'm looking for suggestions. So far I wanted to do Rio-Buzios or something like that but probably there are better ideas for solo travellers. Also, which one is the best month to go there, January or March?

I'd like some fun at night (a good place to drink a great caipirinha or something) and good places to take pictures (I'm an amateur photographer). I'm also interested on beaches but they aren't the most important thing for me.

Comment: Without knowing what you are interested in this is going to be very hard to answer. Wildlife, scenery, music, gastronomy, sun, beaches, ...

Comment: If you would like to go to the beach, March is better. It is hot, but not so much crowded. Also, usually, the prices decrease after February.

Comment: Actually this year I arrived at Carnaval time and stay the whole month of March after that. There are seriously too many possibilities in Brazil and you must really narrow down a zone or interest, for example I covered all of the central coast from Ilha Grande to Olinda, plus Fernando de Noronha. Brazil is so huge that if you do not got by zone then you will spend too much time in transit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, March is better than January; it will be a bit cooler and you leave the carnival rush behind.

You don't state how long you're going. If it's a short trip (1-2 weeks), staying close to Rio and perhaps making one foray is a good plan. Overland travel is slow, because distances are long. But, a flight to something like Iguazu might be worth it. Or, you could take a bus to Minas Gerais and spend a few days in and around Ouro Preto.

Rio is very photogenic, has good beaches, decent restaurants, and everyone serves a good caipirinha.